# What is the name of the following file format [category] key=value

Tags: file, text, file-format

What is the name of the file format that is mostly used for profiles. Example below:

```
[profile 1]
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3

[profile 2]
key1=value1a
key2=value2a
key3=value3a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format matches that of an [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).

> INI is an informal format, with features that vary from parser to parser (INI dialects). Some features are more shared across different parsers than others and can be considered as the hard core of the format (e.g. square brackets for sections, newlines for delimiting different nodes, etc.). Attempts to create parsers able to support as many dialects as possible exist,[8] and in its most advanced form the INI format is able to express a tree object with a power comparable to that of other structured formats (JSON, XML) using a more relaxed syntax.

Comment: do u know the name of this format? Is it "INI format"?

Comment: Sure, but it's a loose format, so you might be able to find a more-specific name depending on how you're using it.  Normally, I just call things like this "INI Files", which assumes it uses an "INI Format", so to speak.